# Range.Replace not working on Range Formulas find and replace

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am trying to change "=" in formulas to "'=" (basically trying to keep formula as text) but it doesn't work.

```
Set rng = Range("A1:A500")

rng.Replace "=", "'=", xlPart
```

But it is not working for some reason.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I tested the exact code you provided (except I made the range A1:A5) and it works for me, so I think you need to provide more info.  At least you know this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code and it works for me. If you want to try a very similar VBA method you can try this...

```
Sub test()
    For Each R In Range("A1:A5")
        R.Value2 = "'" & R.Formula
    Next
End Sub
```

Also, I'm not sure the context of why you're trying to view formulas as text, but if it's simply to view formulas you can use the "Show Formula" option under the "Formulas" tab.

I did some performance testing to see which is faster... the for loop with direct substitution vs the original Range.Replace method.  At 10 µs/cell, the Range.Replace easily beats the for loop which slugs along at about 80 µs/cell, however!, that's not all there is to be said.  The for loop is slow because VBA is slow at looping through cells.  Theoretically, when it comes to the actual operation, direct substitution should always beat a replace algorithm. So, I modified the for loop to act on an array instead and it really speeds things up at about 2 µs/cell.  Bottom line is that if you've got performance concerns, something like this is the fastest...

```
Sub test()
    Set R = Range("A1:A5000")
    Dim A() As Variant
    A = R.Formula
        For i = 1 To UBound(A)
             A(i, 1) = "'" & A(i, 1)
        Next
    R.Value2 = A
End Sub
```

Comment: P57,It works and would use the direct substitution method...thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the **Replace()** function, not the **.Replace** method:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim Rng As Range, r As Range
   Set Rng = Range("A1:A500").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

   For Each r In Rng
      r.Value = Replace(r.Formula, "=", "'=")
   Next r
End Sub
```